# Issue with retrieving object data on IE 8 on Windows XP or 2003

Tags: javascript

This is an interesting problem that I am facing with JavaScript and IE8 on Windows XP and Windows 2003. I create an object on the page and then retrive information about that object (for example, its version). When trying to get the version, I am running this code:

```
var myObject = document.getElementById(objectId);
console.log(myObject.version);
```

What is interesting is that this code works on every single browser except IE8 on Windows XP and 2003. I've done some debugging and this is where things get interesting.

myObject is *not* null but myObject.version is undefined. So what I did is I added an alert in between so the code is now as follows:

```
var myObject = document.getElementById(objectId);
alert(myObject.version);
console.log(myObject.version);
```

The alert results in "undefined", however, the console.log is now resulting in the actual version. If I add an alert before this alert of anything (let's say alert("something")) then the second alert has the actual version now. I am assuming this is a timing issue (for some reason the object needs sometime to be able to provide the data stored in it?) but I am not sure what kind of timing issue this is or how to approach it.

Sorry for the long description but any help is appreciated.

Comment: What type `object` of? Flash or just a DOM element? Maybe you should use `setTimeout` if it's related time issue.

Comment: Depending on what element your `myObject` refers to, this can be quite normal. `alert` is blocking, so it gives the browser a chance to _finish the retrieving cycle_, while your first form requires browser to _immediately response_.

Comment: To answer qeremy's question: it is a DOM object. As for passerby's comment, the issue is that adding a timeout for example is not going to be useful. What is the right timeout? What if it needs more time? What is the right way to get this actually done the right way?

Comment: What's this `version` ? DOM objects don't normally have this property.

Comment: The version is a custom property that is added one this object was created.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use jQuery.data to attach something to DOM elements, and it's crossbrowser.

Comment: Lucassp, appreciate the suggestion, however, I am only doing the retrieval part not the creation. I will take a look at the creation part to see if I can work with it though.

Comment: Not sure, but if it's changed by other script, try [`onpropertychange` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa743098(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById doesn't return an object. It returns a DOM element. So, you expect to see a .version property in a DOM element, which by the official W3C specification is missing (or at least I don't know about this).

I'm not sure what you are expecting to see in .version, but if it is something custom then you should create a custom object like that:

```
var o = { version: "..." }
console.log(o);
```

You said that this may be a time issue. If that's true then I'll suggest to try to access the .version property after the DOM is fully loaded. You can use jQuery for the purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myObject = document.getElementById(objectId);
   alert(myObject.version);
   console.log(myObject.version);
});
```

You can add a setTimeout in your function till the .version property is there.

```
var f = function(callback) {

   var check = function() {
       var myObject = document.getElementById(objectId);
       alert(myObject.version);
       console.log(myObject.version);
       if(typeof myObject.version !== "undefined") {
           callback(myObject.version);
       } else {
           setTimeout(check, 1000);
       }
   }

   setTimeout(check, 1000);

}
```

Comment: The only problem is that the function is called by an outside javascript function. In other words, it is being called from the outside so adding this ready statement does not work in my case.

Comment: You said that .version works in some browser. What is the value returned. Is it the version of the browser or ?

Comment: No it is the version of the object itself. So for example, let's say the version of the object itself (which represents a version of a browser plugin) is 2.0 then it will return 2.0.

Comment: Aham ... so the external library probably adds this property sometime. I'll suggest to include another file before that external source, which sets this property to something like "0". So, at least your outside javascript function will work without an error.

Comment: so the problem is that 0 wouldn't work, I understand the suggestion but the problem is that if I do not get a version let's say > 1.5 I will have to display completely different information than if I do get that. You are right, the version is added externally, but my only issue is that I cannot keep waiting (set a timeout) because it could take 1 second and it could take 3 or 4, right?

Comment: Yep, the interval vary. I think that this timing issues came, because the DOM is not fully loaded and will suggest to try somehow guarantee that.

Comment: Is there a way to guarantee that within a function? Saying wait "within" the function before executing something?

Comment: Can you try to put your initialized javascript code at the end of the DOM. I.e. the code, which runs everything to be at the end of file. You can also try to include the problematic outside function at the end. Probably will help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22300/discussion-between-user220755-and-krasimir-stefanov-tsonev)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the `<script>...</script>` tag with the js code at the end of the html file? In my opinion, the code is executed when the DOM is not ready. If you put it in the end, then it will be executed after it's loaded.